# How should I name In-App Billing's Product Id?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I’m trying to setup In-app Billing service and add the only subscription(month).
There are some naming rules for Product IDs:

> Product IDs are unique across an app's namespace. A product ID must
>   start with a lowercase letter or a number and must be composed of only
>   lowercase letters (a-z), numbers (0-9), underscores (_), and periods
>   (.). The product ID android.test is reserved, as are all product IDs
>   that start with android.test.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-list-setup

My question

Is there a significant difference between product id names:

- myapp.subscription.month
- myapp_subscription_month
- myapp.subscription_month
- …

They all are allowed by google rules and can't be modified later, so what is the best practice for naming product ids?

Comment: Questions about Google Play platform not directly involving programming are considered off topic here on Stackoverflow

Comment: There is really no difference. I usualy do full package name suffixed with some id... com.example.android.monthly1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. Do whatever works best for you.